# Qt, multiple threads, QFuture,Watcher, setting up and getting results

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qfuture

I am trying to perform multiple long-running initializers on threads. I would like to get results as soon as they are available, regardless of order.

I have tried with a simple thread but got stuck where I needed to create multiple threads... and manage them... And the idea of thread pool, futures, thread watcher kept coming up in my research. So, this is my latest try:

```
struct Initializers {
    BigObject *newBigObject;
    bool newValue;
    int initValue;
};

class BigObject {
public: 
    BigObject(QString) {}
    void initialize(bool, int) {}
};

class MyClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public: 
    MyClass() {
        connect(&m_futureWatcher, SIGNAL(resultReadyAt(int)), this, SLOT(initUsingFutureSlot(int)));
        connect(&m_futureWatcher, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(initUsingFutureSlot()));
    }
    void doImportantWork(QStringList someNames);
    
private slots:
    void initUsingFutureSlot(int);
    void initUsingFutureSlot();
    
private:
    void createThreadConnections();
    //void initComplete(BigObject *);
    
    QFutureWatcher<void> m_futureWatcher; 
    QVector<Initializers> m_initializersVector;
};

void longInitializer(Initializers &initializers) {
    qDebug() << "Running in thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    initializers.newBigObject->initialize(initializers.newValue, initializers.initValue);
}

void MyClass::doImportantWork(QStringList someNames) {
    qDebug() << QString("Long running process using %1 thread(s)").arg(QThread::idealThreadCount());
    
    // Prepare the vector.
    foreach (QString someName, someNames) {
        BigObject *newBigObject = new BigObject(someName);
        Initializers initializers;
        initializers.newBigObject = newBigObject;
        initializers.newValue = m_appValue;
        initializers.initValue = m_appInit;
        m_initializersVector.append(initializers);
    }

    // Start the work
    m_futureWatcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::map(m_initializersVector, longInitializer));
    //m_futureWatcher.waitForFinished();
}

// This does not get called
void MyClass::initUsingFutureSlot(int index) {
    qDebug() << "Finished" << index;
    //initComplete(m_initializersVector.at(index).newBigObject);
}

// This does not get called
void MyClass::initUsingFutureSlot() {
    qDebug() << "Finished"
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyClass task;
    task.doImportantWork(QStringList() << "Hello" << "World");
    return app.exec();
}
```

This version of my code is based on [QT5 Tutorial QProgressDialog with QtConcurrent](https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QtConcurrent_QFutureWatcher_QProgressDialog_map.php) which is the only complete example I was able to find that works with multiple threads.

One problem - their `QFutureWatcher`'s type is `void` - and I could not find any way to modify the code to use a different type - and not give compile errors. That is why I made the vector they use a class member, to grab the values from there.

My understanding is that the vector gets the slot applied to every member of it - based on documentation.

So, I ran it, but nothing happens. The debug message shows that the threads are running. But the `resultReadyAt` or `finished` and their corresponding slots are not called. In addition, closing the program says `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`, so they don't finish and close, as I expected them being handled by the Watcher.

I can make things work with `QtConcurrent::run` !!!!

I am stuck.

**Questions:**

- How can I make this QFuture / QFutureWatcher work ? What am I missing in my code or what am I doing wrong to make the threads not finish ?
- How can I make the template non-void (to retrieve results easier ?)
- I have `m_futureWatcher.waitForFinished();` commented because that would block the GUI thread, I think - is that correct ?
- Is there a better option to run multiple threads ? the word `ThreadPool` comes to mind but I have seen no examples that I can use - that can notify of completion. I did find a nice example to emulate a ThreadPool ([NetResultsIT](https://github.com/NetResultsIT/qt-threadpool/tree/master/src)), but I expect Qt should have something functional.
- When closing program, I get `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`. I was under the assumption that threads are closed when done, how should I clean up ? Is deleting the watcher enough ?

I am so lost, fighting these threads for over a week, and they're winning :( Thank you for any help or example.

Using Qt 5.15

Comment: post `BigObject::initialize` and `main`

Comment: @mugiseyebrows For the sake of the example, `initialize` can be empty, and `main` can be identical to the `main` from the linked Qt example, calling `doImportantWork` instead of `show`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example how `QThreadPool` works

```
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QRunnable>

class MyRunnable : public QRunnable
{
public:
    MyRunnable():QRunnable(){}
    void run(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId() << " i " << i;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(new MyRunnable);
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(new MyRunnable);
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(new MyRunnable);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0x32c0 i 0
0x32f8 i 0
0x32f8 i 1
0x32f8 i 2
0x32c0 i 1
0x32c0 i 2
0x25a0 i 0
0x25a0 i 1
0x25a0 i 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, but I don't see any way to know when a thread is complete, and get the info from it.